# python social auth error when running syncdb

Tags: python, django

I recently just setup the python-social-auth 0.1.8 so i can support social authentication in my django 1.5 projects, here is [a link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-social-auth/#installation). I'm running Python 3.3 right now. I have followed all of the install directions [here](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html). So I have done this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ( ... 'social.apps.djangoapp.default', ... )
```

I am using Postgres 2.0 with PostGIS extensions if that matters. When I try to run syncdb to setup the models and sync the database I keep getting the error object of type 'map' has no `len()`. I am sure it is from the social app and not from any of my existing models. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks and I apologize if this has already been answered in another thread, I looked but haven't had any luck finding an answer.

Comment: Upgrade your python to at least 3.3.2 and try again

Comment: Can you post full traceback? It's difficult to say from above information.